# I have a CSV with NO line delimiter. How can I efficiently add one?

Tags: csv, import, delimiter

I have a CSV file (4.7 million characters) that I am struggling to import into a spreadsheet.
It seems the line delimiter is just a space...and yet there are also spaces after every comma.
What can I do to correctly organize this data in a spreadsheet?

I have tried using Google sheets import and Microsoft Excel import.

Example of current CSV

73, 5/11/2018,Vet Check,Result:Pregnant Multiple, , 73, 5/19/2018,Move To String/Pen,Move To:16, , 73, 5/22/2018,Mastitis,Treat. Name:Spectramast, Treat. Type:Intramammary, Comments:4 Times, Move To:1673, 5/25/2018,Move To String/Pen,Move To:10, , 73, 5/28/2018,Move To String/Pen,Move To:11, , 73, 7/20/2018,Vet Check,Result:OK - Confirmed PG, ,

Where the linebreaks should be.

73, 5/11/2018,Vet Check,Result:Pregnant Multiple, ,

73, 5/19/2018,Move To String/Pen,Move To:16, ,

73, 5/22/2018,Mastitis,Treat. Name:Spectramast, Treat. Type:Intramammary, Comments:4 Times, Move To:16

73, 5/25/2018,Move To String/Pen,Move To:10, ,

73, 5/28/2018,Move To String/Pen,Move To:11, ,

73, 7/20/2018,Vet Check,Result:OK - Confirmed PG, ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you could apply this kind of regex https://regex101.com/r/HU13Um/2

Then using sed and tail, if you run

```
<input sed -r 's/([0-9]{2}, *[0-9]+\/)/\n\1/g' | tail -n +2 >output
```

you will have

```
73, 5/11/2018,Vet Check,Result:Pregnant Multiple, , 
73, 5/19/2018,Move To String/Pen,Move To:16, , 
73, 5/22/2018,Mastitis,Treat. Name:Spectramast, Treat. Type:Intramammary, Comments:4 Times, Move To:16
73, 5/25/2018,Move To String/Pen,Move To:10, , 
73, 5/28/2018,Move To String/Pen,Move To:11, , 
73, 7/20/2018,Vet Check,Result:OK - Confirmed PG, ,
```